# Are NPAPI plugin security issues same as a downloadable app that connects to the internet

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, npapi

I want to build a cross-platform helper app that lets my users scan the desktop filesystem and find/upload the original, hi-res version of a JPG image they have previously uploaded. The scan may try to match by filename, EXIF data, or by comparing visual attributes using computer vision algorithms.

I read the following and get a little frightened:

> **Security considerations**
>   Including an NPAPI plugin in your extension is dangerous because plugins have unrestricted access to the local machine. If your plugin contains a vulnerability, an attacker might be able to exploit that vulnerability to install malicious software on the user's machine. Instead, avoid including an NPAPI plugin whenever possible.

My other option is to build a download/install native desktop app that runs in the background. But this approach is would also have unrestricted access to the local machine + my servers via the internet.

Both approaches require the user to download/install native code - but the NPAPI plugin has the promise of easier access and a common framework. So are the security issues the same or is one approach generally preferred over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, both plugins and a regular app have the same kind of access - so installing either one requires quite a bit of trust. There is a difference in attack surface however: while an application is normally something that can only be started by the user, a plugin is accessible to every website (restricting access to selected websites is possible but this protection itself can fail). Also, if you want to package an NPAPI plugin in a Chrome extension you have to consider that [Chrome Web Store requires manual review before accepting such extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) (and distributing extensions from your own site is pretty hopeless with the changes made in Chrome 21). But it can potentially provide a better user experience. All in all: not an easy choice to make.